Can you run multiple geyser plugins on one validator?
This is a few questions in one:
Can you multiple geyser plugins in one single validator/RPC node?
If so, how?
If not, why not? (Hopefully the answer to this question is not just "the validator code to do so was just not added")

Of course you can! The --geyser-plugin-config flag takes in a list of files, ie:
solana-validator --geyser-plugin-config <FIRST_CONFIG> --geyser-plugin-config <SECOND_CONFIG>


thanks, you're the best jon!
